# gforth : Attempt to use zero-length string as a name

Tags: forth, gforth

I am a beginner in this language : *GForth*.

Can someone with some experience tell me what the problem is in the code below ?

Here is a definition.

```
: collatzcount
variable count
0 count !
{ ini } ini
begin dup 1 <> while dup . syr repeat .
count ? ;
\ redefined collatzcount   ok
```

At this point apparently nothing is wrong. So let us try :

```
1 collatzcount
```

output

```
:213: Attempt to use zero-length string as a name
1 collatzcount>>><<<
Backtrace:
$7F21F04AB710 throw
$7F21F04B0008 name-too-short?
$7F21F04B1990 header
$7F21F04B1A00 Create
$7F21F04FD460 Variable
```

What is this mysterious "*Attempt to use zero-length string as a name*" ?

Just in case one wants to know, this is the definition of *syr* :

```
: syr dup 2 mod 0 = if 2 / else 3 * 1 + endif ;
```

But this is probably irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`variable` is a defining word and works correctly only at interpreter level i.e. not within a colon definition. (This is true for all Forths, but the *symptoms* of violating it may vary; in particular a 'state-smart' implementation will likely give you an error during the definition, rather than waiting till you run it.)

Also `count` is a [preexisting (and standard) word](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/String-Formats.html#index-count-_0040var_007b-c_002daddr1-_002d_002d-c_002daddr2-u--_007d--core-1987); using it as a `variable` makes the standard word inaccessible and may break things.

Finally there is no benefit in making `ini` a local when the only use you make of it is to immediately re-push it.

Net:

```
: syr dup 2 mod 0 = if 2 / else 3 * 1 + endif ;

variable cnt
: collatzcount 0 cnt ! begin dup 1 <> while dup . syr repeat . cnt ? ;
1 collatzcount -> 1 0 ok
3 collatzcount -> 3 10 5 16 8 4 2 1 0  ok
```

This runs, but the count is always 0 because you never changed it. I suspect from the name you wanted to increment `cnt` in the loop so at the end it prints the number of loops executed (i.e. steps) before reaching 1:

```
: collatzcount 0 cnt ! begin dup 1 <> while cnt @ 1+ cnt ! dup . syr repeat . cnt ? ;
3 collatzcount -> 3 10 5 16 8 4 2 1 7  ok
```

etc. (Break into lines and add comments to taste.)

Comment: This answer taught me  a lot of details I was not aware of. Your interpretation about the counter is totally correct. It is just that when I wrote the post I was concerned about fixing the annoying error not about anything else.

Comment: BTW, in a standard Forth system, a 'state-smart' implementation for [`variable`](https://forth-standard.org/standard/core/VARIABLE) is not allowed. And Gforth is a standard compliant system.